# Filter on pandas dataframe with DATE and specific time

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
eui  BatV  TempC_DS  TempC_SHT  \
0    58A0CB0000101DB6   NaN       NaN        NaN   
1    58A0CB0000101DB6   NaN       NaN        NaN   
2    58A0CB0000101DB6   NaN       NaN        NaN   
3    58A0CB0000101DB6   NaN       NaN        NaN   
4    58A0CB0000101DB6   NaN       NaN        NaN   
..                ...   ...       ...        ...   
245  58A0CB0000101DB6   NaN       NaN        NaN   
246  58A0CB0000101DB6   NaN       NaN        NaN   
247  58A0CB0000101DB6   NaN       NaN        NaN   
248  58A0CB0000101DB6   NaN       NaN        NaN   
249  58A0CB0000101DB6   NaN       NaN        NaN   

             EventEnqueuedUtcTime                                    id  \
0    2021-02-24T10:34:13.8060000Z  beeae3f6-8e1c-4eab-a4e3-72a7ccef383d   
1    2021-02-24T10:34:34.1070000Z  f1e5d54a-0eba-4ae7-8ab9-cb3ba4c74b24   
2    2021-02-24T10:39:22.0980000Z  fc3dc5b5-3529-4c5e-a1db-d13a1d849fcf   
3    2021-02-24T10:44:21.7910000Z  5bb9fa04-20da-4862-9eaf-203f3bb6b1e5   
4    2021-02-24T10:49:22.8080000Z  20e59b34-357a-48cf-bcc5-0e857bb52f54   
..                            ...                                   ...   
245  2021-02-25T07:50:08.5040000Z  8eca61b9-a1b3-4cf1-adf5-5bc90208c37e   
246  2021-02-25T07:55:08.0550000Z  b43e0f32-b5ad-4c8f-ac02-0fea62c4f959   
247  2021-02-25T08:00:08.7940000Z  85516c14-bf8d-4d62-9ddf-6289e5eb3071   
248  2021-02-25T08:05:08.2260000Z  0d13773c-81fd-4038-bbe9-6def2262b4e3   
249  2021-02-25T08:10:09.2350000Z  16b29ea2-5bf5-489f-bfc5-34f301a4587d   

                         _rid  \
0    AqMcAKHcB0mACgAAAAAAAA==   
1    AqMcAKHcB0mBCgAAAAAAAA==   
2    AqMcAKHcB0mCCgAAAAAAAA==   
3    AqMcAKHcB0mECgAAAAAAAA==   
4    AqMcAKHcB0mGCgAAAAAAAA==   
..                        ...   
245  AqMcAKHcB0nzCwAAAAAAAA==   
246  AqMcAKHcB0n0CwAAAAAAAA==   
247  AqMcAKHcB0n2CwAAAAAAAA==   
248  AqMcAKHcB0n3CwAAAAAAAA==   
249  AqMcAKHcB0n5CwAAAAAAAA==   

                                                 _self  \
0    dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAKHcB0k=/docs/AqMcAKHcB...   
1    dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAKHcB0k=/docs/AqMcAKHcB...   
2    dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAKHcB0k=/docs/AqMcAKHcB...   
3    dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAKHcB0k=/docs/AqMcAKHcB...   
4    dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAKHcB0k=/docs/AqMcAKHcB...   
..                                                 ...   
245  dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAKHcB0k=/docs/AqMcAKHcB...   
246  dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAKHcB0k=/docs/AqMcAKHcB...   
247  dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAKHcB0k=/docs/AqMcAKHcB...   
248  dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAKHcB0k=/docs/AqMcAKHcB...   
249  dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAKHcB0k=/docs/AqMcAKHcB...   

                                      _etag  _attachments         _ts  \
0    "ef029dec-0000-0d00-0000-60362ba60000"  attachments/  1614162854   
1    "ef02befa-0000-0d00-0000-60362bba0000"  attachments/  1614162874   
2    "f002c9c1-0000-0d00-0000-60362cda0000"  attachments/  1614163162   
3    "f102f18c-0000-0d00-0000-60362e070000"  attachments/  1614163463   
4    "f2021852-0000-0d00-0000-60362f330000"  attachments/  1614163763   
..                                      ...           ...         ...   
245  "4103b1ac-0000-0d00-0000-603757ad0000"  attachments/  1614239661   
246  "42039845-0000-0d00-0000-6037590a0000"  attachments/  1614240010   
247  "4203ded9-0000-0d00-0000-60375a3a0000"  attachments/  1614240314   
248  "43034b51-0000-0d00-0000-60375b640000"  attachments/  1614240612   
249  "4303b5b0-0000-0d00-0000-60375c620000"  attachments/  1614240866   

     DecibelValue  
0             NaN  
1             NaN  
2             NaN  
3             NaN  
4             NaN  
..            ...  
245          59.0  
246          51.0  
247          68.0  
248          48.0  
249          55.0  

[250 rows x 12 columns]
```

And I want to use the EventEnqueuedUtcTime which has date + time.

I would like to leave in the dataframe only all rows with  greater than 25/02/2021 at 8.20 AM.

But I am not sure how to filter like this

Answer (score 2):

Convert column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['EventEnqueuedUtcTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EventEnqueuedUtcTime'])

df = df[df['EventEnqueuedUtcTime'] > '2021-02-25 08:20:00']
```